# Windows 8 requiring startup screen after reboot

Tags: windows-8

I recently bought an acer aspire v5 running windows 8. After an accidental power loss, I tried to boot my PC. Now, while bios is loading it asks for a user startup password, not the windows login password. I've never had this startup password screen before.

I am able to launch setup via f2 and f12 but after exploring all the advance options, I am still being redirected to a (enter user password screen).

I tried all the startup repair options including using a windows 8 DVD but no luck.

Any help please.

Comment: sounds like the firmware settings were reset.  I assume this is before you have an option of going into the BIOS/UEFI configuration?

Comment: Is the password being requested by Windows or the BIOS? Do you see a Windows logo/color scheme or is it all monochrome?

Comment: Could you make a photo of the screen in question?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting this during the BIOS loading, you won't be able to run a DVD etc.

Try hitting F2 or DEL during the BIOS loading. Windows 8 shutdown interacts with the BIOS, so it may not have achieved the right state after a power loss. You may be able to enter BIOS setup this way. There's some info [here](http://community.acer.com/t5/Notebooks-Netbooks/How-do-I-access-the-BIOS-on-a-Acer-Aspire-V3-571G-9636/td-p/13751) about it.